# bash - processing output one line at a time

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I read that xargs was good for processing the output of a command one line at a time (and it is).
I have the following line in my script.

```
./gen-data | awk '{printf $2 " "; printf $1=$2=$3=""; gsub (" ", "", $0);if(length($0) == 0){ print "0000"} else{print $0}}' | xargs -t -n2 -P1 bash -c 'datatojson "$@"' _
```

It produces the right output, there is no question of that. However, gen-data produces something like 1000 lines, and what I really would like is for this command to execute after each line, not after 1000 lines (It's clearly stopping regularly to get more input).

Here is what gen-data looks like:

```
candump $interface &
while true; do
    while read p; do
        cansend $interface $(echo $p | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}');
    done < <(shuf $indoc)
done
```

(`cansend` sends data to an interface and `candump` reads from that interface and outputs it onto the screen, but I wager that's not too relevant). In any case `candump` seems to be continuously streaming output, but when I pipe that into `awk` and `xargs`, it becomes chunked. Is it just because I used `shuf`? I would think that since it's going through the interface, and being read on the other side, it would be less chunked than shuf provides.

Comment: Wy are you using `shuf`? Does this script work without using it? (I know it **should**, but it is necessary to rule it out)

Comment: @FelipeLema I just tried it with `cat` instead of `shuf` and it's doing the same thing. Not sure how else I can feed it into that loop, I'm not very experienced in scripting.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117501/in-bash-script-how-to-capture-stdout-line-by-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the same command, this time using multiple hacks to [avoid buffering](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html):

```
./gen-data | gawk '{printf $2 " "; printf $1=$2=$3=""; gsub (" ", "", $0);if(length($0) == 0){ print "0000"} else{print $0}; fflush(stdout)}' | stdbuf -o0 xargs -t -n2 -P1 bash -c 'datatojson "$@"' _
```

Mind the change from `awk` to `gawk` and the use of `fflush`. You can also try `mawk -Winteractive`.
Also mind that I added `stdbuf -o0` before xargs. You can also try the latest at the beginning with `./gen-data`

Comment: Worked perfectly. What does the `-o0` do on the `stdbuf` command?

Comment: As stated in the [`stdbuf` `man` page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stdbuf#end): sets the buffering of the command as "unbuffered"