# Run commands from a pipe in realtime

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

If I have a pipe like `cat /dev/somedevice | grep 'test'` that output commands, like for example `echo 'test 17'`, the commands appear in realtime (everytime `/dev/somedevice` delivers some line). If I however pipe the commands to `sh`, they won't be invoked imediately because of pipe buffering. So

```
cat /dev/somedevice | grep 'test' | sh
```

wont execute commands in realtime.

Is there any other way that would? With `xargs` or something?

Comment: So you want `sh` to interprete each line separately as soon as each is fed to `sh`?

Comment: See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/945935/384482) to [a very similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/945902/bash-processing-output-one-line-at-a-time/)

`cat /dev/smd | stdbuf -o0 grep 'test' | stdbuf -o0 sh`

Comment: The stdbuf method works, so the answer to this question is almost the same as to "how to get unbuffered pipes" questions all around..  Maybe you post a similiar answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try `--line-buffered` to make a continuous stream:

```
cat /dev/somedevice | grep --line-buffered 'test' | sh
```

Comment: This is nice, but works for example pipe only (using grep). I would favor a more general answer like in the comments above.